# How do you obtain the Golden Weapons and Clues achievement in Max Payne 3?

Tags: max-payne-3

I was wondering how to achieve the Golden Weapons and Clues in Max Payne 3.
I tried it by choosing chapter 2, then I found all the weapon parts and clues but when chapter 3 was initiated and I quit, I seem to have made no progress in collecting them.
Do I have to play through the story the "normal" way or was it because I had the infinite bullettime cheat activated?

Comment: Most games won't allow you to progress through achievements when cheats are enabled, specifically to ensure you're earning those achievements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are unable to gain achievements when cheats are activated in Max-Payne 3.

Sorry.